# openGL displaying multiple objects

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-shader

I'm using openGL 3.3 to draw 4 polygons in a window. My program calculates the vertices of 2 polygons (m and n sides) and applies some transformation to draw and animate 2 polygons of m sides and 2 of n sides.

My problem is that I need to store the vertices of the 2 polygons in different memory locations, since I want to apply different transformations, but I'm not able to retrieve and display both the objects from my vertex shader.

```
#version 330

in vec3 a_vertex;
uniform mat4 transform;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(a_vertex, 1.0);
}
```

This shader shows only the first 2 objects (whose vertices are stored in  *location 0*). The same happens if I write `layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_vertex;`.

Otherwise writing `layout (location = 1) in vec3 a_vertex;` I can only see the other two polygons (whose vertices are stored in  *location 1*).

This seems reasonable. Now my question is: how can I show all the 4 polygons?

P.S.: I think [Multiple objects drawing (OpenGL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458089/multiple-objects-drawing-opengl)
previous question contains the answer but the explanation is so high level that I cannot translate it into code.

Comment: is this related to hardware accelerated instancing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood what *shader locations* are and what they're used for. Locations are designator for separate attributes within the same vertex passed to a shader. Color is an attribute and has a location. Surface normal is an attribute and has a location. Texture coordinate is an attribute and… well you get the idea.

What you have there however are *different* vertices. All you have to do is simply make draw calls for your different vertices. Just call `glDraw…` several times or put all your different vertices into a single buffer and draw them all at once.